# Database: Foreign Key Enforcement

Tags: database-design, spring-roo, foreign-key-relationship

I'm sure this could be answered but don't exactly know where.

Preface:

Ours is a billing solution. Application design is pretty simple, we create web store for businesses and provide credentials to business owners.

Business owners can log in and create relevant products, categories etc. They can also register devices they might want to use for billing.

The master entities can be created using web interface whereas billing takes place on native applications for devices.

**Database Tables:**

```
BUSINESS: id, name etc. - Business Info Table
CATEGORY: id, business_id, name etc. - Product Categories
PRODUCT: id, category_id, name etc. - Products
```

**Application:**

Spring ROO based web application. Spring MVC as GUI technology

**Problem:**

As mentioned earlier owners have to use their credentials to log into web store. So at the time they have started creating entities the webapp knows relevant business id which is transparently stored for all categories, products etc.

While creating products, user can select category in which a product may fall.

The question is: Is it a good idea to store business_id in product table? Because we are only going to populate categories relevant to business at the time of generating product GUI. The same could be the case with all associated tables where such rules are enforced in GUI.

As some of you might know, ROO takes the approach of creating service for each CRUD operation. So if we decide not to store business_id with product, the business rule could be circumvented if someone tries to call service with category id which does not belong to relevant business. Or is it a good idea to leave database design intact and focus on securing the services.

If you have any relevant pros and cons please post it here too.

Thanks in advance :)!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue you face is called multi-tenancy. You can read more about the pros and cons of the options here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

I prefer the tenant-per-schema approach.

You can use JBoss Hibernate's Multi-tenancy feature to automate this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html